# Flex mx:DataGrid row index

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, adobe

Is it possible to dynamically show row index for `DataGrid` rows ?
I have a static `ArrayCollection` which is set to be `DataGrid`'s data provider and I would like to always have row numbering for each populated row (e.g. in a column called "#").

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, create a labelFunction that returns the ArrayCollction's getItemIndex for the current object, plus 1.  [Example](http://www.cflex.net/showFileDetails.cfm?ObjectID=735)

Comment: Awesome.  Interestingly I've never had to do that.